# Qt eventfilter does not detect objectName

Tags: c++, qt

My program uses a ui-form-file that consists, next to other widgets, of a label called "grip" (its objectname).
As I am running the code, I see the code line `grip was not detected` and I am wondering why the mouse click on the label is not recognized. I also have defined a `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` that works as intended if I click on that label.

```
bool Note::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type()==QEvent::MouseButtonPress){
        qDebug() << "in Note::eventFilter" << endl;
        if (target->objectName()=="grip")
        {
            lastClicked="grip";
            qDebug() << "lastClicked == grip" << endl;
        }
        else
            qDebug() << "grip was not detected" << endl;
     }
    return false;
}
```

What may be a reason for `target->objectName()=="grip"` being false, if I click on that target and it is called "grip"?

EDIT: That is how my event functions are defined:

```
void Note::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
       qDebug() << "Left mouse button click detected";
        ...
```

the main event filter is initialised in the Note's constructor:

```
Note::Note(std::vector<Note *> *nListIn){
    qDebug() << "in Note::Note()" << endl;
    ui.setupUi(this);
    installEventFilter(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    this->show(); //must be after the Qt::FramelessWindowHint
    nList = nListIn;
    nList->push_back(this);
    qDebug() << "Size of nList (aka noteList)" << nList->size() << endl;
}
```

EDIT 2: Found some description, might this be the reason?

> If your widget only contains child widgets, you probably do not need
>   to implement any event handlers. If you want to detect a mouse click
>   in a child widget call the child's underMouse() function inside the
>   widget's mousePressEvent().

Comment: change log to: `qDebug() << "grip was not detected" << target->objectName();` to see object name which invoked event filter. (`endl` is not needed it is always appended in case of `qDebug`).

Comment: Ah, clever and very useful. It says "Note", the name of the overall main widget the label is part of. Do you know what and if I might have to change in the QtDesigner?

Comment: If you use `eventFilter`, why do you define `mousePressEvent` also? Show your `installEventFilter` calls.

Comment: As eventFilter is of type `bool` I thought it would be a pre-step that filters all events before they get passed to other event handlers like `mousePressEvent`, but as you say I might be wrong with that. I have edited my initial post as you wanted.

Comment: And moreover, I don't know how to get the event's target without the eventFilter. In python it is working somehow (getting the target's name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, if you install an event filter only on itself (by calling `installEventFilter(this)`, the following holds:

```
bool Note::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *) {
  Q_ASSERT(target == this);
  ...
}
```

Obviously, the target won't ever be called `grip`, unless you've named the instance of your `Note` class that way.

If you want to filter the events on the grip label, then you must install the event filter on that label, not on the `Note` widget. The `Note` widget will only get events that the children have ignored, and by that time, it doesn't matter that you "filter" them - it's too late.

Your setup code could contain, for example:

```
ui.grip->installEventFilter(this);
```

Or, assuming nothing about the structure of the `ui` class:

```
QWidget * grip = findChild<QWidget*>("grip");
if (grip) grip->installEventFilter(this);
```